# Find a matching or closest value in an array (from a given value)

Tags: matlab

How can I search and find, for a given target value, the closest value in an array?
For example here is my array:

**0, 54, 10, 11, 152, 7**

For example, when I search with the target value 6, the code shall return 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```matlab
% Array to search in, modified to have more than one closest value.
x = [0, 5, 10, 11, 152, 7];

% Target value.
target = 6;
```

Calculate absolute "distances" between each array element and the target value.

```matlab
% Temporary "distances" array.
temp = abs(target - x);
```

Find the minimum "distance" value by [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html). Compare the temporary "distances" array to that minimum value (resulting in some binary array), and then use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the corresponding indices, which finally can be used to get the values from the original input array `x`.

```matlab
% Find "closest" values array wrt. target value.
closest = x(find(temp == min(abs(target - x))))
```

The output looks like this:

```matlab
closest =
   5   7
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. For my program i just need one closest value 5 or 7.. How can i avoid to get 2 values?

Comment: @PhMO  For example, use `closest = x(find(temp == min(abs(target - x)), 1, 'first'))`, where the `find` method is set to just find `1` (one) entry, starting at the `first` index. Alternatively, you could also use `last`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`interp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) with the '`nearest'` option:

```
V = [0, 54, 10, 11, 152, 7];
x = 6;
result = interp1(V,V,x,'nearest');
```